# Como eu utilizo o WHERE usando KnexJS como uma condicional?

Tags: node.js, knex.js

To fazendo uma rota de put para update, e usando o knexJS para atualizar os dados no banco de dados, e no meu código a solução que achei foi esta abaixo:

```
dbKnex("game").where({ id: id }).select("*").then(data => {
        if(data != "") {
                var { nome, preco } = req.body;

                dbKnex("game").where({ id: id }).update({ nome: nome, preco: preco}).then(data => {
                res.sendStatus(200);
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            }) 
        } else {
            res.sendStatus(404);
        }
    })
```

Nessa primeira pesquisa do database ele retorna os dados que foram achados em um select, que depois são usados numa verificação se eles existem no database (`if(data != "")`), mas quero outra solução que não precise desse select, somente um condição na parte do WHERE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você poderia fazer de uma maneira mais simples passando apenas a condicional e os parâmetros a serem atualizados. O `data` retorna array com número de registros que foram alterados. Podem ser `[1]`, `[2]`, `[3]`, ..., mas creio que esse `id` seja único, então ele retornaria somente o registro que foi atualizado. Se o `data[0]` for `undefined`, significa que o `id` não foi encontrado na base de dados, logo nenhum registro foi alterado.

O código poderia ser escrito desta forma:

```
// não precisa do "select"
dbKnex('game')
  .where({ id: id })
  .update({ nome: nome, preco: preco })
  .then((data) => {
    if (!data[0]) { 
      // se o "data[0]" for undefined, significa que não alterou nenhum
      // registro pois não achou nenhum que segue a condicao.
      res.sendStatus(404);
    } else {
      res.sendStatus(200);
    }
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Este código dispensa a necessidade de usar o `select`, pois já estamos aplicando a lógica para caso não tenha sido encontrado nenhum registro no banco em `if (!data[0])` e também evita de ter que fazer duas consultas no banco, uma para encontrar e outra para atualizar.

---

- detalhe: `if(data != "")` essa comparação usando somente `!=` é perigosa. Evite usar ela.
- o `data` seria um array com numero de registros alterados. Logo, para o seu caso, esperariamos um array do tipo `[1]` para o registro alterado, ou `[]` se nenhuma registro foi alterado.